# getElementById not working for extensions on Gmail

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension for Gmail, and trying to execute the following content script:

`document.getElementById("gbqfq").value = "foobar";`

but it always fails with the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Although, when I use console and run the same code, it works properly.

I'm already using `"all_frames": true, "run_at": "document_end"` parameters in the manifest.json file. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Chrome extensiIt might be related to the scope of iframes.
If you use JQuery, thry something like:

```
$('iframe').find("#YOUR-ID")
```